# filtering elements of matrix by row in python scipy/numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How can I filter elements of an `NxM` matrix in `scipy/numpy` in Python by some condition on the rows?

For example, just you can do where(`my_matrix != 3`) which treats the matrix "element-wise", I want to do this by row, so that you can ask things like where `(my_matrix != some_other_row)`, to filter out all rows that are not equal to `some_other_row`. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you have a matrix

```
a = numpy.array([[0, 1, 2],
                 [3, 4, 5],
                 [0, 1, 2]])
```

and you want to get the indices of the rows tha are not equal to

```
row = numpy.array([0, 1, 2])
```

You can get these indices by

```
indices, = (a != row).any(1).nonzero()
```

`a != row` compares each row of `a` to `row` element-wise, returning a Boolean array of the same shape as `a`.  Then, we use `any()` along the first axis to find rows in which any element differs from the corresponding element in `row`.  Last, `nonzero()` gives us the indices of those rows.

Comment: You can also just use `(a != row).any(axis=1)` directly in most cases.